# Datatables & Bootstrap pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using datatables & Bootstrap in a JSP page

https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html

and I would like to add the **onchange** function in the selector of 
*Show N entries*

Would this be possible ??????????

this is the code in my JSP:

```
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                var table = $('#deviceTableId').DataTable({
                    "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {"targets": 'nosort', "orderable": false, "width": '30%'},
                        {"targets": [0], "width": '20%'},
                        {"targets": [1], "width": '35%'},
                        {"targets": [2], "width": '15%'},
                    ]
                });
                table.columns().every( function () {
                    var that = this;
                    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                            that
                                .search( this.value )
                                .draw();
                        }
                    } );
                } );
            });

        </script
```

>

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for getting the change event.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#example').DataTable();

 $(".dataTables_length label select").change(function(){
  alert(this.value);
 });

});
```

Refer this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrrtsteg/12/)